# svg code animation doesnt work on edge, but works on any other browser

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, microsoft-edge

I am working on a svg typewriter effect with `dashoffset` and `dasharray` set at 1000 or 500 both and so animation is in effect on chrome, safari, firefox and my pc, but on Microsoft Edge it doesn't work, because ms Edge is so much more different.

I don't know how to make it work. The problem is with dasharray and dashoffset.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes curse {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes curse {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

#dot1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: curse 12s linear forwards;
  animation: curse 12s linear forwards;
}

#Pline {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: curse 1.5s linear forwards .1s;
  animation: curse 1.5s linear forwards .1s;
}

#Pline1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: curse 1.5s linear forwards .28s;
  animation: curse 1.5s linear forwards .28s;
}

#O1line {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.6s linear forwards .4s;
  animation: curse 0.6s linear forwards .4s;
}

#Rline {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.8s linear forwards 0.68s;
  animation: curse 0.8s linear forwards 0.68s;
}

#Rline1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 0.78s;
  animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 0.78s;
}

#Tline {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1s;
  animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1s;
}

#Tline1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.15s;
  animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.15s;
}

#Fline_1_ {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.37s;
  animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.37s;
}

#Fline {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.47s;
  animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.47s;
}

#Fline2_1_ {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.21s;
  animation: curse 0.5s linear forwards 1.21s;
}

#O2line {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.6s linear forwards 1.6s;
  animation: curse 0.6s linear forwards 1.6s;
}

#Lline {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.7s linear forwards 1.9s;
  animation: curse 0.7s linear forwards 1.9s;
}

#Iline {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 1s linear forwards 2.1s;
  animation: curse 1s linear forwards 2.1s;
}

#O3line {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -webkit-animation: curse 0.6s linear forwards 2.38s;
  animation: curse 0.6s linear forwards 2.38s;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="597.06px" height="141.014px" viewBox="0 0 597.06 141.014" enable-background="new 0 0 597.06 141.014" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="R_1_">
 <defs>
  <path id="rmask" d="M168.617,32.97c1.032,0.147,1.769-0.59,2.654-1.032c2.359-1.032,5.16-1.327,7.814-1.474
   c1.179-0.147,2.359-0.147,3.538-0.295c1.18-0.147,2.211-0.295,3.391-0.295c5.455-0.59,10.762-1.327,16.217-1.18
   c4.275,0.147,8.551,0.59,12.827,1.327c1.032,0.147,2.064,0.442,3.096,0.589c1.032,0.147,2.064,0.442,3.096,0.737
   c2.211,0.442,4.423,1.18,6.487,2.064c1.327,0.59,2.654,1.327,3.98,2.063c1.18,0.737,2.506,1.917,3.539,2.949
   c2.064,2.358,3.096,5.16,3.244,7.961c0,0.737,0,1.475,0,2.064c-0.147,0.442-0.147,0.737-0.147,1.031l-0.295,1.032
   c-0.295,1.18-0.442,2.359-1.032,3.539l-0.737,1.769c-0.294,0.442-0.589,1.032-0.884,1.622c-0.442,0.442-0.737,1.032-1.032,1.621
   l-1.179,1.475c-0.885,1.18-1.622,2.507-2.801,3.538c-0.885,0.737-1.769,1.327-2.506,2.212c-0.295,0.295-0.737,0.737-1.179,1.033
   c-0.442,0.442-0.885,0.737-1.327,1.031c-3.686,2.212-7.224,4.276-11.057,6.192c-1.18,0.59-2.506,1.032-3.686,1.622
   c-1.327,0.442-2.654,0.885-3.833,1.475c-1.327,0.441-2.654,0.736-3.98,1.031c-1.327,0.442-2.654,0.737-3.981,1.032
   c-1.622,0.295-3.243,0.59-4.865,0.885c0.59,0.295,1.18,0.59,1.622,0.885c3.98,2.358,7.519,5.308,10.91,8.256
   c3.98,3.686,8.698,6.635,12.237,10.763c0.59,0.59,1.474,0.737,1.917,1.474c0.442,1.032,1.769,1.622,2.359,2.507
   c1.18,1.769,2.949,3.243,4.423,4.718c2.064,2.063,3.981,4.128,5.75,6.339c1.769,2.507,3.686,5.16,6.339,7.52
   c0.59,0.442,1.032,1.032,1.622,1.475c0.295,0.295,0.442,0.441-0.147,0.884c-0.737,0.442-1.474,0.885-2.506,0.885
   c-2.801,0.295-4.718,0.59-6.34,0.147c-2.948-0.885-4.718-2.506-6.044-4.275c-0.885-1.032-1.622-2.063-2.506-3.096
   c-1.622-1.917-3.391-3.833-5.308-5.75c-3.686-3.686-7.519-7.371-11.647-10.763c-4.128-3.391-8.551-6.634-13.121-9.436
   c-2.654-1.621-5.603-3.096-8.404-4.275c-0.147,0-0.295-0.147-0.442-0.147c-0.442,1.622-0.884,3.391-1.622,5.013
   c-0.295,0.737,0,1.475-0.442,2.212c-0.737,1.031-0.442,2.211-1.032,3.243c-1.032,1.917-1.327,3.98-1.77,6.045
   c-0.589,2.653-1.032,5.308-1.769,7.961c-0.295,1.475-0.737,2.948-0.884,4.423c-0.147,0.885-0.147,1.622-0.147,2.359
   c0,0.441,0.147,0.736,0.147,1.179v0.59l0.147,0.147c1.622,0.295-0.295,0-1.77-0.147l-0.147,0.147
   c-0.295,0.147-0.737,0.59-0.884,0.885c-0.147,0.147-0.147,0.295-0.147,0.295c0,0.147,0,0.147,0,0.147
   c0,0.147-0.147,0.295-0.295,0.295c-0.442,0.442-1.18,0.59-1.769,0.59c-0.59,0-1.18-0.147-1.77-0.442
   c-0.295-0.147-0.589-0.442-0.884-0.59c-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.295-0.442s-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.442
   c-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.442c-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.147l-0.147-0.147c0.147-0.59,0-0.147,0-0.295v-0.147
   v-0.147c-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.295-0.295-0.442c-0.147-0.294-0.295-0.589-0.442-1.031c-0.294-0.59-0.442-1.18-0.442-1.917
   c-0.295-1.327-0.147-2.506,0.147-3.833c0.147-1.327,0.442-2.654,0.737-4.128c0.59-2.654,1.327-5.308,1.917-8.108
   c1.475-5.308,2.949-10.615,4.276-15.775c0-0.147,0.147-0.442,0.147-0.59c0-0.295,0-0.59,0-1.032c0-0.737,0-1.327,0-2.063
   c0-0.59,0-1.18,0.147-1.77c0.147-0.442,0.147-0.737,0.147-1.18c-0.147-0.737,0-1.474,0.147-2.358
   c0.147-1.917,1.032-2.949,2.064-2.802c0.147,0,0.147,0,0.147,0c0.295-1.326,0.442-2.653,0.737-3.98
   c0.147-1.475,0.442-3.096,0.59-4.571c0.147-1.621,0.295-3.096,0.295-4.57c0-3.243-0.442-6.34,0-9.436
   c0.147-0.737-1.327-1.622,1.622-2.211c0.885-0.147,1.622-0.295,2.506-0.59c0.59-0.147,1.179-0.295,1.917-0.295
   c0.442,0,0.885,0,1.327-0.147c0.737-0.147,1.769-0.295,2.653-0.442c2.212-0.147,3.686,0.295,3.686,1.18
   c-0.295,0.442,0.295,0.884,0.442,1.326c0.295,0.737,0.295,1.475,0.147,2.064c0,0.737-0.295,1.475-0.442,2.211
   c-0.442,1.18-0.737,2.359-0.885,3.392c-0.295,1.474-0.295,2.801-0.442,4.128c0,1.475-0.147,2.801-0.442,4.128
   c-0.442,2.212-1.032,4.423-1.622,6.488c1.032-0.147,2.064-0.442,3.096-0.59c2.359-0.59,4.865-0.885,7.077-1.622l1.769-0.442
   l0.737-0.295l0.885-0.295l3.391-1.031c2.064-0.885,4.128-1.77,6.192-2.802c3.833-2.063,7.372-4.57,10.025-7.519
   c2.654-2.949,4.423-6.192,5.013-9.583c0.147-0.147,0-0.295,0.147-0.442v-0.442c0-0.295,0-0.59-0.147-0.885
   c0-0.59-0.147-1.18-0.442-1.622c-0.295-0.441-0.589-0.884-0.884-1.179c-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.295-0.295l-0.442-0.295
   c-0.442-0.147-0.737-0.295-1.032-0.442c-1.474-0.737-3.538-1.327-5.75-1.77c-1.18-0.295-2.359-0.442-3.539-0.59
   c-1.179-0.147-2.506-0.295-3.686-0.441c-2.801-0.295-5.75-0.442-8.698-0.442c-2.949,0.147-5.897,0.295-8.846,0.589
   c-2.948,0.295-5.897,0.885-8.846,1.475s-5.897,1.327-8.846,1.917c-0.59,0.147-1.327,0.59-2.064,0.737
   c-0.737,0.147-1.327,0.147-2.211-1.032c-0.442-0.59-1.032-1.18-1.622-1.77c-0.442-0.442-0.737-0.885-1.032-1.474
   c0-0.442-0.295-0.737-0.59-1.032c-0.59-0.59-1.032-1.327-1.327-2.064C166.701,35.035,167.143,33.56,168.617,32.97z
    M172.451,108.455c0,0.147,0,0.147,0.442,0.295c0.295,0,0.442-0.147,0.442-0.147c0-0.147,0-0.295,0-0.442
   c0.147-0.59-0.295-1.327,0.147-1.917c0.737-1.031,1.032-2.211,1.032-3.538c0-0.737-0.147-1.474,0.589-2.063
   c0.885-0.737,1.032-1.475,0.885-2.359c-0.147-1.032-0.147-1.916,0.737-2.801c0.295-0.295,0.295-0.737,0.442-1.032
   c0.147-1.327,0.442-2.653,1.474-3.833c0.442-0.59,0.885-1.18,0.147-2.064c-0.295-0.295-0.295-0.59,0-0.885
   c0.147-0.295,0.295-0.442,0.442-0.736c-0.295-0.147-0.737-0.295-1.032-0.442c0.147,0.295,0.147,0.59,0.147,0.884
   c0,0.295-0.295,0.59-0.295,0.885c-0.59,1.475-1.179,2.949-1.622,4.275c-0.442,1.77-0.885,3.392-1.327,5.013
   c-0.884,2.654-1.327,5.308-2.653,7.814C172.008,106.243,172.451,107.423,172.451,108.455z M174.367,116.121
   c0.295-0.295,0.147-0.442-0.442-0.59c-0.59,0.295-0.295,1.475,0.59,1.917c0-0.147,0-0.295,0-0.295
   C174.367,116.711,174.072,116.416,174.367,116.121z M180.412,89.142c-0.147,0.442-0.442,1.032-0.737,1.475
   c-0.147,0.147-0.294,0.295,0,0.737c0.295,0.295,0.147,0.59-0.442,0.736c-0.295,0.147-0.295,0.295-0.295,0.442
   c-0.442,1.77-0.885,3.539-1.327,5.308c-0.294,1.327-0.737,2.507-1.327,3.833c0,0-0.147,0.147,0,0.295
   c0.737,0.295,0.147,0.442,0,0.59s-0.295,0.295-0.442,0.59c-0.442,0.737,0,1.475,0,2.359c0,0.147-0.295,0.295,0.295,0.442
   c0.295,0,0.147,0.146,0,0.146c-0.737-0.146-0.59,0.147-0.737,0.295c-0.442,1.032-0.737,2.212-0.884,3.392
   c-0.295,1.474-0.737,2.948-0.442,4.57c0,0.295,0,0.442,0.147,0.737c0.737-0.295,0.737-0.737,0.59-1.327
   c-0.147,0-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.295s0.294-0.295,0.442-0.442c0.442-0.59-0.884-1.475-0.147-2.064
   c0.147-0.146,0.442-0.294,0.59-0.441c0-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.442c-0.295-0.737,0.442-1.18,1.18-1.622
   c-0.295,0-0.737-0.147-0.885-0.295c-0.147,0-0.147-0.147,0-0.295c0.147-0.442,0.295-0.885,0.442-1.327
   c0-0.147,0-0.147,0.147-0.295c0.147,0,0.295,0,0.442,0s0.147-0.147,0-0.147c-0.147-0.294-0.59-0.589-0.59-0.884
   c-0.147-0.295,0.442-0.59,1.18-0.442c0.147,0,0.294,0.147,0.442,0.147c0.295,0,0.295-0.295,0-0.295
   c-0.295-0.147-0.589-0.295-1.032-0.295l1.179-1.475c0-0.147,0.147-0.147,0.147-0.295c-0.147-0.147-0.442-0.442-0.442-0.59
   s0.59-0.147,0.885,0c0.147,0,0.147-0.442,0.147-0.589c-0.295-0.295-1.032-0.442-0.59-0.59c0.59-0.442,0.295-0.885,0.147-1.327
   c-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.295,0-0.442c0.737-0.737,0.737-1.622,1.18-2.506c0.442-0.737,0.147-1.622,0.442-2.507
   C180.559,92.532,180.559,90.911,180.412,89.142z M174.367,95.334c0.442,0.147,0.589,0,0.589-0.147
   c0.147,0,0.147-0.295-0.294-0.295c-0.59-0.147-0.442,0.147-0.59,0.295C174.22,95.187,173.925,95.334,174.367,95.334z
    M174.22,122.903c0,0,0,0-0.147,0C174.072,122.903,174.072,122.903,174.22,122.903z M174.367,123.051h-0.147
   C174.367,123.051,174.367,123.051,174.367,123.051z M174.367,123.198c0-0.147,0-0.147,0-0.147
   C174.367,123.198,174.367,123.198,174.367,123.198z M175.251,121.724c-0.442-0.147-0.884-0.147-0.737-0.147h0.147l0.147,0.147
   c0.147,0.147,0.294,0,0.294,0C175.251,121.724,175.251,121.724,175.251,121.724z M182.034,87.814
   c-0.295-0.147-0.59-0.295-0.885-0.295c0,0.147,0,0.147,0,0.295c-0.147,0.295-0.147,0.442-0.295,0.59
   c0,0.147,0.147,0.147,0.295,0.147c0.295,0.147,0.295,0,0.295,0c0.147,0,0.147,0,0.147-0.147
   C181.739,88.257,181.886,87.962,182.034,87.814z M181.444,74.251c0.147,0,0.147,0,0.295,0.147c0.147,0,0.295,0.147,0.442,0.295
   c0.147-0.147,0.147-0.147,0.147-0.147c0.147-0.442,0.147-0.885-0.147-1.474C181.296,73.366,181.444,73.809,181.444,74.251z
    M182.328,72.335c1.032-0.295,0.295-0.737,0.59-1.18C181.886,71.303,181.739,71.745,182.328,72.335z M182.476,70.565
   c0.295,0,0.442,0,0.295-0.147c0,0,0.147-0.147-0.147-0.295c-0.442,0-0.295,0.147-0.295,0.295
   C182.328,70.418,182.181,70.565,182.476,70.565z M182.476,68.501c-0.147,0.147-0.295,0.295,0.295,0.442
   c0.295,0,0.295-0.147,0.295-0.147c0-0.147,0.147-0.295-0.442-0.442C182.328,68.354,182.476,68.501,182.476,68.501z
    M184.834,72.188c-0.442-0.295-0.589-0.59-0.147-0.885c0.295-0.147,0.147-0.295-0.442-0.442c0,0.147,0,0.295-0.147,0.295
   c-0.59,1.032-0.737,2.063-0.885,3.096c0.59-0.295,1.327-0.442,1.917-0.59c0,0,0,0,0-0.147c0,0,0.147-0.147,0-0.147
   c-1.032,0-0.59-0.294-0.442-0.294c0-0.147-0.442-0.442,0-0.59C185.129,72.482,185.129,72.335,184.834,72.188z M184.098,68.648
   c0,0.442,0,0.737,0,1.032v0.885c0,0,0.147,0.147,0.442,0.147c0.442,0,0.59,0,0.295-0.147c-0.147-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.295
   c0.737-0.442-0.147-1.032,0-1.475c0-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.442-0.295C183.95,68.501,184.098,68.648,184.098,68.648z M189.995,78.674
   c0.442-0.147,0.885-0.442,1.475-0.295c0.442,0,0.737-0.147,0.884-0.736c-0.737-0.147-2.064,0.294-2.949,0.736
   C189.552,78.526,189.7,78.526,189.995,78.674z M233.192,53.021c-0.442,0.737-0.885,1.474-1.475,2.211
   c-0.294,0.295-0.442,0.59-0.442,1.032c0.147,0.59-0.147,1.18-0.885,1.327c-0.295,0.147-0.442,0.295-0.59,0.442
   c-1.622,2.653-3.98,4.865-6.487,6.929c-0.885,0.737-1.917,1.475-2.949,2.212c-1.179,0.59-2.211,1.179-3.391,1.622
   c-0.147,0.147-0.295,0.147-0.295,0.295c0,0.737-0.59,0.59-1.032,0.737c-0.295,0-0.737,0.147-1.032,0.295
   c-1.327,0.442-2.506,1.475-3.833,2.212c-0.147,0-0.589,0.147-0.442,0.59c0.147,0.147-0.147,0.147-0.295,0
   c-0.295-0.442-0.59-0.147-0.737-0.147c-1.18,0.295-2.211,0.589-3.244,0.884c-0.589,0.295-1.032,0.442-1.622,0.59
   c-0.442,0.147-1.032,0.295-1.622,0.442c-1.327,0.442-2.801,0.885-4.128,1.327c-1.474,0.295-2.801,0.737-4.128,1.18
   c-0.59,0.147-1.032,0.295-1.474,0.589c0.884,0.442,1.917,0.147,2.654-0.294c0.295-0.147,0.442-0.295,0.737-0.295
   c0.295,0,0.59,0,0.885,0c0.59,0.147,1.179-0.295,1.769-0.59s1.18-0.737,1.77-0.737c0.442,0,0.884,0.295,1.179,0.147
   c0.295,0,0.59-0.295,0.737-0.442c0.589-0.295,1.179-0.442,1.769-0.442s1.179,0,1.917,0.147c-0.295-0.147-0.295-0.59-0.295-0.737
   c0.147-0.295,0.442-0.295,0.59-0.295c0.885-0.295,1.769-0.59,2.654-0.885c0.147,0,0.295,0,0.442,0s0.295,0.147,0.295,0.295
   c0.294,0,0.294-0.147,0.442-0.295c0.295-0.294,0.59-0.884,0.885-1.179c0.442-0.295,1.179-0.147,1.622,0.442
   c0,0,0,0.147,0.147,0.295c0.295,0.294,0.59,0,0.59-0.295s-0.147-0.59-0.442-0.885c1.032-0.147,2.064-0.442,3.096-0.737
   c0.295,0,0.59-0.147,0.737-0.295c0.147-0.147,0.147-0.59,0.442-0.737c0.147-0.147,0.737,0.147,0.737,0.442
   c0,0,0.885-0.442,0.885-0.59c0.147-0.442-0.295-1.032,0.442-1.032c1.032-0.147,1.474-0.884,1.917-1.474
   c0.147-0.295,0.442-0.443,0.589-0.59c0.885-0.295,1.622-0.737,2.212-1.18c0.737-0.442,1.327-1.032,1.917-1.475
   c1.474-0.884,2.064-2.506,3.096-3.538C231.57,58.329,232.749,55.822,233.192,53.021z M225.378,115.974
   c0.147,0.147,0.295,0.147,0.442,0c0.295-0.295,0.295-0.295,0.295-0.442c-0.147,0-0.147-0.146-0.295-0.294
   c-0.442-0.442-1.327-0.59-1.474-1.18c-0.442-1.18-1.327-1.917-2.359-2.654c-0.737-0.442-1.475-0.736-1.475-1.621
   c0-1.032-0.737-1.475-1.622-1.917s-1.769-0.885-2.064-1.916c-0.147-0.442-0.442-0.59-0.737-0.885
   c-1.032-0.885-2.064-1.77-2.654-2.949c-0.295-0.59-0.59-1.326-1.769-1.179c-0.59,0-0.737-0.147-0.885-0.295
   c-0.442-0.885-0.737-1.77-1.769-2.064c-0.295-0.147-0.59-0.295-1.179-0.147c-0.295,0.442-0.295,0.59,0,0.737
   c0.147,0,0.442,0,0.589,0.147c0.442,0.147,1.032,0.295,0.442,1.032c0,0.147,0,0.147,0.147,0.147c0.59-0.147,1.032,0,1.327,0.147
   c0.147,0.295,0.442,0.59,0.589,0.737c1.032,1.031,2.064,2.211,3.244,3.243c1.179,1.18,2.359,2.358,3.538,3.538
   c1.917,1.917,3.981,3.686,5.16,6.045C223.461,115.09,224.641,115.385,225.378,115.974z M209.308,35.918
   c0-0.295-0.147-0.295-0.442-0.295c-0.147,0-0.59-0.147-0.59,0.295c-0.147,0.295,0.147,0.147,0.295,0.147
   C208.866,36.213,209.308,36.361,209.308,35.918z M208.571,34.297c-0.147,0-0.295,0-0.295,0.295s0.295,0.147,0.442,0.147
   c0.59,0,1.18,0,1.917,0h1.475c0.295,0,0.295-0.147,0.295-0.442s0-0.442-0.295-0.295c-0.147,0.147-0.442,0.295-0.59,0.147
   C210.487,33.56,209.603,34.297,208.571,34.297z M212.109,35.771c-0.147,0-0.442,0-0.442,0.295s0.295,0.147,0.442,0.295
   c0.147,0,0.295,0.147,0.295-0.147C212.552,35.918,212.257,35.771,212.109,35.771z M216.532,35.476
   c1.179,0.147,2.211,0.295,3.244,0.442c0.147,0,0.294,0.147,0.442-0.147c0-0.147,0-0.295,0-0.441
   c-0.295-0.442-0.442-0.885-1.032-0.442c-0.147,0.147-0.442,0.295-0.442,0c0-0.442,0.147-0.295,0.442-0.442c0,0,0,0,0.295-0.147
   c-0.59-0.147-1.032-0.147-1.622-0.295c0,0-0.295,0-0.295,0.147c-0.147,0.885-0.442,0.442-0.737,0.295
   c-0.295,0-0.737,0.295-0.885-0.147s-0.442-0.295-0.59-0.147c-0.589,0.442-1.179,0.442-1.769,0.147
   c-0.295-0.295-0.442-0.147-0.737,0.295c0.295,0,0.442,0.147,0.59,0.147C214.468,35.035,215.5,35.33,216.532,35.476z
    M213.141,100.052c0.295,0.442,0.59,0.885,0.885,1.327c0,0.146,0.147,0.294,0.59,0.294c0.589,0,0.737,0.147,0.589,0.737
   c0,0.147,0.147,0.295,0.147,0.295c1.475,1.327,2.801,2.507,4.128,3.833c1.032,0.885,1.917,1.917,2.653,3.097l0.147,0.147
   c0.885-0.295,0.59,0.147,0.59,0.295c0.147,0.147,0.147,0.442,0.295,0.59c0.295,0.736,1.327,0.884,2.064,1.474c0,0,0,0.295,0.59,0
   c0.147-0.147,0.147,0,0,0.147c-0.442,0.295-0.295,0.442-0.147,0.59c0.59,0.885,1.327,1.917,2.211,2.653
   c1.032,1.18,1.917,2.359,3.244,3.244c0.295,0.147,0.442,0.442,0.737,0.442c0.295-0.59,0-1.032-0.589-1.18
   c-0.147,0-0.295-0.147-0.295-0.147c-0.147-0.147,0-0.442-0.147-0.59c0-0.737-1.622-0.442-1.622-1.18c0-0.295,0.147-0.59,0-0.736
   c-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.442-0.147c-0.737-0.295-0.737-1.032-0.59-1.77c-0.147,0.147-0.59,0.295-0.737,0.295
   s-0.295,0-0.295-0.147c-0.295-0.295-0.589-0.737-0.884-1.18c0,0-0.147-0.147,0-0.147c0-0.147,0.147-0.295,0.147-0.295
   c0.147-0.147,0-0.147-0.147-0.147c-0.295-0.147-0.885,0-1.18-0.147s-0.147-0.59,0.442-1.031c0.147,0,0.295-0.147,0.295-0.147
   c0.295-0.295,0.147-0.442-0.147-0.295s-0.737,0.295-1.032,0.59l-0.442-1.622c0-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.295-0.295s-0.442,0-0.59,0
   c-0.147-0.147,0.147-0.59,0.442-0.737c0.147,0-0.295-0.295-0.442-0.295c-0.442,0-1.032,0.442-0.885,0
   c0-0.59-0.589-0.737-1.179-0.737c-0.147-0.147-0.295-0.147-0.295-0.295c-0.295-0.884-1.032-1.474-1.474-2.211
   c-0.442-0.737-1.622-1.032-2.211-1.77C216.237,101.673,214.763,100.789,213.141,100.052z M215.795,36.361
   c-0.59-0.885-1.474-0.295-2.359-0.59C213.878,36.656,214.911,36.803,215.795,36.361z M215.647,106.98c0,0-0.147-0.147-0.442,0
   c-0.442,0.442-0.147,0.442-0.147,0.59c0.147,0,0,0.147,0.294,0C215.647,107.275,215.795,107.128,215.647,106.98z M221.545,37.983
   c-0.295-1.18-2.359-1.77-4.423-1.327C218.449,37.983,220.365,36.951,221.545,37.983z M232.012,119.66
   c-0.147,0.59,1.032,1.179,1.917,1.031c-0.147,0-0.295-0.147-0.295-0.147c-0.442-0.294-0.885-0.441-0.885-0.736
   S232.602,119.513,232.012,119.66z"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="rmask_1_">
  <use xlink:href="#rmask"  overflow="visible"/>
 </clipPath>
 <path id="Rline1" clip-path="url(#rmask_1_)" fill="none" stroke="#b695ff" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
  M166.378,40.021c0,0,21.5-8,41.167-5.667c19.667,2.333,26.333,4.667,25.5,15.833c-0.833,11.167-12.167,17.833-23.333,21.167
  c-11.167,3.333-34.754,8.794-34.754,8.794s22.254-1.294,62.921,47.872"/>
 <path id="Rline" clip-path="url(#rmask_1_)" fill="none" stroke="#b695ff" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
  M186.211,46.188c0,0-3.094,39.495-17.75,82.375"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Have tried playing with the numbers, but no use, it still doesn't work

Comment: You don't have to post whole code here, create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this link may become dead in future and question won't be helpful to others. I see similar blocks in css, so maybe it won't be that long if you show only part of it (or maybe you could demonstrate it on simpler svg than >800 lines of code)

Comment: The necessary code is present in the question and shows the described behavior, so I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the time of writing (Jan 2019), animating `stroke-dashoffset` is not supported in Microsoft Edge and given Microsoft's track record with speedy improvements to Edge, you can expect it to not work anytime soon.

Please refer to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6493460/

Unfortunately, my recommendation is to render the animation properly on non-IE/Edge browsers and only show the final result on IE/Edge (so that they still see something on the page). To determine the user's current browser, refer to [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769).

Comment: more precisely, _animating_ `stroke-dashoffset` is not supported. If used statically, the property can be used.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention that, even though it's in the link. Will edit the answer accordingly.